# How to pass id to $resource along with query params?

Tags: angularjs

I have a service named MyService in which I have defined a resource like this

```
MyResource: $resource('my/url/to/resource/:id')
```

Now when I am calling my resource using the following code, its not sending correct request to server.

```
var search = {page: 1, rows=10 };
MyService.MyResource.get(search).$promise.then(function(result) {
...
});
```

Its requesting `url my/url/to/resource?page=1&rows=10`
How to pass correct id to MyResource?

Comment: put {id : <theId>} in your search variable. your `:id` placeholder in resource url will get replaced by the `id` property of your search object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define resource like this:

```
MyResource: $resource('my/url/to/resource/:id', {id: '@id'})
```

and use it this way:

```
var search = {
    page: 1,
    rows: 10,
    id: 12312
};
MyService.MyResource.get(search).$promise.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put {id : ""} in your `search` variable. your `:id` placeholder in resource url ('my/url/to/resource/:id') will get replaced by the `id` property of your search object.

```
var search = {id:"<theId>", page: 1, rows=10 };
MyService.MyResource.get(search).$promise.then(function(result) {
...
});
```

Comment: /my/url/to/resource/:id is a different server call and /my/url/to/resource is different